# Microsoft Teams Desktop App does not recognize my camera

Tags: microsoft-teams

I had OBS previously installed and used its camera on Teams. However, after uninstalling OBS, Teams show only OBS-camera in the settings as shown below:

[image]

I want to use my USB camera instead. How can I make Teams provide me the USB camera option in the menu? I have tried uninstalling and re-installing Teams but nothing changes.

But Teams does successfully shows my USB camera on Microsoft Edge.

Comment: What did you do to tell Teams to use the OBS camera? Have you tried undoing it? Also, if you're using Teams in Edge you aren't using a Teams "app". What are your browser settings?

Comment: Have you restarted and/or tried plugging the camera into a different USB port?  If you are still being offered OBS-Camera then OBS has not been fully uninstalled.

Comment: OBS camera automatically showed up in Teams when OBS was installed. I have restarted my PC and unistalled OBS, but still see only OBS-camera option.

Comment: Reinstall Teams.  Or physically disconnect your camera.  Shut-down.  Power up.  Connect your camera.  Either should work.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat. I uninstalled Teams > Restarted PC >  Re-installed Teams > Disconnected Camera > Opened Teams > Plugged-in the camera, and it still shows OBS-camera option only

Comment: I had problems with Teams and programs that modify video.  I uninstalled everything dealing with video (Teams, OBS, possibly Lens Studio, Logitech Camera, DroidCam), reset, booted a couple of times and put Teams back and problems went away.  Sorry, I can't help.